# GetAllInstances using SimpleInjector

Tags: c#

I had the following implementation for a class QueryProcessor:

```
public TResult Process<TResult>(INewQuery<TResult> newQuery) 
{
  var handlerType = typeof(INewQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(newQuery.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
  IEnumerable<object> handlers = this.container.GetAllInstances(handlerType);    
  dynamic handler = handlers.ElementAt(0);
  return handler.Handle((dynamic)newQuery);
}
```

The INewQuery is defined as:

```
public interface INewQuery<TResult> 
 { 
 }
```

The INewQueryHandler is defined as:

```
public interface INewQueryHandler<TNewQuery, TResult>
where TNewQuery : INewQuery<TResult>
{
TResult Handle(TNewQuery query);
}
```

I register using container as shown below:

```
this.container = new SimpleInjector.Container();

this.container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(Cai.Apex.Library.Infrastructure.INewQueryHandler<,>),
    container.RegisterAll,
    assemblyLoader.GetAssemblies());
```

Now if I create a concrete query like:

```
public class GetDriver : INewQuery<Apdriver> 
 {
public string DriverId { get; set; }
}
```

Then create an instance of it:

```
GetDriver driver = new GetDriver {DriverId = "AXN"};
```

Then invoke Process on queryProcessor:

```
 var result = this.queryProcessor.Process(driver);
```

It all works fine and the container finds the handler for the query fine and all is good.

Now for another scenario, I just know the name of the query, in this case GetDriver and through a service call, I get the value for its property, "AXN". 
 I need to create an instance of the query GetDriver in this scenario. So up front, the registration of the all the INewQuery types is done and the name of the query and its type is stored in a dictionary.

```
 foreach (var assembly in assemblyLoader.GetAssemblies())
  {
    var types = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                from i in type.GetInterfaces()
                where i.IsGenericType &&
                ((i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(INewQuery<>)))
                select type;

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
      this.newBusinessTypes.Add(type.Name, type);
    }
  }
```

Later this newBusinessTypes is used to get the type using the name "GetQuery" that came in and an instance of it is created as shown below:

var specificQuery = Activator.CreateInstance(matchedQuery);` (here matchedquery is the matching type for the query name). 
 The matchedquery is defined as dynamic type.

Then I invoke the queryprocessor process method doing:

```
var result = this.queryProcessor.Process(specificQuery);
```

What is happening in the Process method is that, the handlerType gets defined fine but the container.getallinstances for that type does not return a matching handler. So the next call to get the 0th element fails and so the Handle method cannot be invoked.

I am not sure, what is going wrong here and why the handler is not being retrieved by the container. I am stumped.

Please advise,

Thanks,

Amit

Comment: I believe `GetAllInstances` only returns registrations which were registered via RegisterAll `container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric( typeof(Cai.Apex.Library.Infrastructure.INewQueryHandler<,>), (service, impls) => container.RegisterAll(service, impls), assemblyLoader.GetAssemblies());`